# How to compare 2 JSON objects using Karate tool

Tags: karate

1. URL 1 --> post request --> JSON respose 1
2. URL 2 --> post request --> JSON respose 2

How to compare response 1 and response 2 ?

response 2 will have extra attributes so cannot directly use match command

Response1 { name : hello, country : ABCD}
Response2 { name : hello, country: ABCD, state: xyz}

Want to compare only name and country attributes and don't want to hardcode comparison like
 match response1.name == response2.name

In future extra attributes may be added and don't want to modify the script frequently

Or

Is there anyway to pass both the responses to JavaScript function from karate and perform comparison

Like call read ('comparison.js') response1 response2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Please read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains

```
* def response1 = { foo: 'bar', hello: 'world' }
* def response2 = { foo: 'bar', hello: 'world', extra: 'blah' }
* match response2 contains response1
```