# How to do comparison of json object on nesting level in karate

Tags: karate

how to compare a nested json response with another response

actualResponse:

```
  {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "accountOrder": {
               "id": "11450027922158000",
               "accountType": "SAVINGS",
               "servicePrice": 400
               }
     }
```

expectedReponse:

```
 {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "accountOrder": {
               "accountType": "SAVINGS"
     }
     }
```

I have tried the following methods for comparison:

```
   * match actualResponse contains expectedResponse // failed with reason: actual value has 2 more key(s) than expected
```

Our requirement is we don't want to hardcode comparison like

```
 * match actualResponse.accountType contains expectedResponse.accountType
```

We may need to add more attributes in expected and don't want to modify the script frequently

Comment: @PeterThomas, my requirement is same like [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245848/how-to-compare-2-json-objects-using-karate-tool and why scenarios are passed even if there is a mismatch in key values when we use "contains only"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts

```
* def accountOrder = { "accountType": "SAVINGS" }
* def expected = { status: SUCCESS, accountOrder: '#(^accountOrder)' }
* def response =
"""
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "accountOrder": {
    "id": "11450027922158000",
    "accountType": "SAVINGS",
    "servicePrice": 400
  }
}
"""
* match response == expected
```